# Isn't it wise that LaTeX package developers, make an option in all their math packages...?

Tags: macros, packages, package-writing, package-options

> **Question:** Isn't it wise that LaTeX package developers, make an option in all their math packages something like `\usepackage[opt-cmd[user-define]]{math-package-name}` such that we able to use only optional commands of package and not all package?

e.g. I (I think all) prefer to never use `mathabx` package because it changes a lot of other things; in this case it would be very nice if we have an option like `\usepackage[\widebar]{mathbx}` that allow to use only `\widebar` command. Now think about other packages `mathtools`, `matheq`, `mathrsfs`,`mathdots`, `mathalfa`, etc.

This is very useful because:

1. It makes users to choose their own desired symbol and not worry about changing in other symbols;
2. It makes users sure that use the packages without worrying about conflicting commands. (errors like: `this command has been defined already`)
3. It allows to developers to not worrying about searching for new name for similar commands that has been defined already in other packages. So it is possible to have  many commands `\bar` but  different effects. but here is the usage of `[user-define]` option. for example in `\usepackage[\chi[\mychi]]{upgreek}` user can assign a new name for `\chi` if he/she want to use both symbols simultaneously or `\usepackage[all[\my+]]{upgreek}` that user can redefine all name `upgreek`, `\mychi`, `\myalpha`, etc. packages by easy to remembering names.
4. New names for similar commands isn't easy to remember for at least new users or who is so lazy for reading manual of packages like me.

> **Request 1:** Can you encounter other good or bad effects of this feature?
>
> **Request 2:** Can you improve this feature?

Comment: Is this a question or a feature request?

Comment: it is totally unclear what your suggested syntax is, or what you want the command to do, the largest part of a math font package is not defining the user commands but setting up the fonts, as in classic tex you can only specify 16 math fonts multiple math packages will always clash, it is not clear how your suggestion addresses that at all.

Comment: also the standard latex optional argument parsing as used by `\usepackage` does not support nested `[]` so  `\usepackage[\chi[\mychi]]{upgreek}` is a syntax error.

Comment: The requests don't make sense. What's the point of discussing a non-existent feature which couldn't be implemented?